# Which Database UI is use with MYSQL? I am new in web developnment

Tags: mysql, database

I Want to install PHP on my computer, so I start with installing PHP and MYSQL, but I thought that how can I see the data which is inserted in the MYSQL database. That's why I am searching for a software for seeing data, tables

Comment: google XAMPP, then watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxo4_DX4ejU

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL Workbench, which can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer toad for mysql, link: [toad for mysql](http://toadformysql.com)